# How to get TextBox from a Editable ComboBox - Winforms

Tags: winforms, combobox

I am using a ComboBox which is editable, i need to get the TextBox used for Editing inside a combobox.

In WPF, I can get the TextBox by using VisualTreeHelper. what's the alternative in WinForms.

Thanks in Advance.

Thanks,

Venkatesan R

Comment: What do you mean by "get the textbox"? what is your goal?

Comment: Hi @ZoharPeled, Thanks for the reply, I meant "An editable Combobox contains a textbox and list box as child controls" isn't it? i need to get that textbox which is a child control for combobox.

Comment: I would imagine you need the text the user has entered, I see no reason for referencing the inner controls directly. hence the question - what is your goal?

Comment: Hi @ZoharPeled my goal is to apply the border style as none, since i can't find any BorderStyle property for the ComboBox, i am trying to get the inner controls and change as i required

Comment: And also i need to set padding value for the text displayed in combobox, since if the textBox height is below 21, the text is hided a little bit at the bottom, so i am trying set bottom padding

Comment: I don't know if that's possible, since the combobox is a windows control. However, you can host a wpf combobox in your winforms application if you need to.

Comment: Hi @ZoharPeled, now i was not able to set TextAlignment for the ComboBox. How can i set ?

Comment: can i get solution for this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35146335/how-can-i-align-text-for-combo-box-in-winforms-in-winforms